# I get an Access denied warning for my connection

Tags: php, connection, database-connection

I have problem with my connection. This is a shared server and I have use SSH to check my database and my tables.
I use the same credential to access them thru the web. However it gives me error. I check for any typo, but they are correct and my sql access and my database don't have username or password. So I only have one user and pass for my host. I have created my tabales and uploaded my pages to the same database with same username and password.

***# Can this problem be the server problem? so whoever established did not configure it correctly?? #***

this is the error:

> Warning: mysql_connect(): Access denied for user 'cop...'@'139.62.63....' (using password: YES) in /home/cop.../homepage/login.php on line 10
>   Could not connect to database

and here is my code, is there anything that I can do? can you think of anything else, but typo ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php

if(!($sqlCon= mysql_connect("139.62.63...","cop..","abcdef")))
    die( "<p>Could not connect to database</p>" );

if (! ($dbCon = mysql_select_db("cop..", $sqlCon)))
    die( "<p>Could not open database</p>" );

// username and password sent from form
$myusername=$_POST['email'];
$mypassword=$_POST['password'];
$submit=$_POST['submit'];

        echo'<form name="Login" method="post">
                <table width="300" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
                    <tr>
                    <td>
                        <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="3"><strong>Member Login </strong></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td width="78">Username</td>
                                <td width="6">:</td>
                                <td width="294"><input name="myusername" type="text" id="myusername"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Password</td>
                                <td>:</td>
                                <td><input name="mypassword" type="text" id="mypassword"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                <td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Login"></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
        </table>
                </form>';

if($submit) {
    // To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
        $myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
        $mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
        $myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
        $mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);

    $sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'";
    $result=mysql_query($sql);

    // Mysql_num_row is counting table row
    $count=mysql_num_rows($result);

    // If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
    if($count==1){

    // Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file "login_success.php"
        session_register("myusername");
        session_register("mypassword");
        header("location:login_success.php");
    }
    else {
        echo "Wrong Username or Password";
    }
mysql_close($sqlCon);
}

    ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: or ip, or username, or the db is not set-up correctly

Comment: No, I use the same password to connect to my database and it is fine :(

Comment: @Dagon what do you mean that is not set up correctly? on my code or when the database was created?

Comment: # Can this problem be the server problem? so whoever established did not configure it correctly?? #

Answer (score 0):

Incorrect password to connect to MySQL. Check your configuration. It's funny that you are creating a login form to verify username password when in fact your application cannot connect to the database.

Comment: LOL you are right , but I can connect to MySQL thru SSH with no problem

Comment: how can I do that? this is not my server. This is temp server given from school to complete my project. Can i have access to those logs? and how?

Comment: # Can this problem be the server problem? so whoever established did not configure it correctly?? #

Comment: You can shell into the mysql server? Is that what you are saying? That has nothing to do with mysql datatabase authentication.